# Google Maps Error: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object - seems to be 'bounds' related

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I import addresses from a google-spreadsheet and put them on a google map. The Location (latitude & longitude) are stored in a variable. I loop through all entries and create the markers. 
The connection between Google Spreadsheet and the website works, but it only shows the first entry. So it seem to be an issue with the loop.

First I thought it is a problem with the Values in the `_location.latitude/_location.longitude` and I tried setting the .value there, but this isn't the issue.

The Loop is in the `_setLocations` Function and from my search, it seems that `var _bounds` or the `_bounds.extend` has some issues

```
_createGoogleMap: function(_mapID){

          var _this = this;

          var _locations = [];

          var _sheetUrl = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/values/Sheet1!A2:U?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

          var _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(_mapID), this._mapProp);

          $.getJSON(_sheetUrl, function(data) {
            $(data.values).each(function() {
              var _location = {};
                _location.latitude = parseFloat(this[8]);
                _location.longitude = parseFloat(this[9]);
                _locations.push(_location);
            });

            _this._setLocations(_map, _locations);

          });
        },
```

```
_setLocations: function(_map, _locations) {

          var _this = this;

          var _bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

          var _infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Content String"
          });
          for (var i = 0; i < _locations.length; i++) {
            var _new_marker = _this._createMarker(_map, _locations[i], _infowindow);

            _bounds.extend(_new_marker._position);
          }
          _map.fitBounds(_bounds);

        },
```

When I 'console.log(_locations);' before the loop, 
I get all the addresses, but after the loop I got nothing
anymore.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A google maps `LatLngLiteral` has the properties `.lat` and `.lng` (not `.latitude` and `.longitude`).

Answer (score 1):

try using a proper LatLng object

```
   my_location  = new google.maps.LatLng(_locations[i].latitude, _locations[i].longitude) ;
   var _new_marker = _this._createMarker(_map, _my_location, _infowindow);
```